# Facebook Graph API error: "FBCDN image is not allowed in stream" for an image on my server

Tags: facebook, image, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm trying to post an item to a user's news feed with an image on my own site. I get the "FBCDN image is not allowed in stream" error which normally occurs when someone tries to include an image that is on Facebook's server, however the image I'm including is on my own server.

```
    var imgSrc = $('.final-badge .badge-background img').attr('src'),
    badgeUrl = $('#largeCrestView').val();

    var obj = {
         method: 'feed',
         //Will need to be retrieved from a hidden text field in ASP environment
         link: badgeUrl,
         picture: imgSrc,
         name: 'All hail my Coat of Charms',
         caption: captionText,
         description: ''
    };
```

This is my code. The imgSrc variable contains a direct link to an image stored locally on my server. The URL is an absolute path as well.

An ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Would help if you included an actual link that you get this error for. Would be better to use console.log(imgSrc) to see that what you're getting is what you think you're getting.

Comment: Good call, I actually worked it out. It was that the location of the image, as I've been informed, was a local URL. Now that It's external I'm not getting that error anymore. Thanks.

Comment: Add that as an answer and accept it yourself so other users can find the answer when they search for that error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually worked it out. It was that the location of the image, as I've been informed, was not publicly accessible. Now that It's external it works fine.